# Paypal Payment Request error

Tags: delphi, paypal

Here is my code regarding the PayPal Payment Request. I am getting a 401 error but I am not sure where it is coming from or how to handle it. I believe it is from my Custom Header configuration.

How to fix it?

```
FUNCTION GetAccessToken :String ;
Var
 AccessToken :TJSONValue ;
BEGIN
  AccessToken := PayPalTokenObj.Get('access_token').JsonValue ;
  Result := AccessToken.Value ;
  PayPalForm.Memo1.Lines.Add('Access Token: ' + Result) ;
END ; {GetAccessToken}

FUNCTION GetTokenType :String ;
Var
 AccessTokenType :TJSONValue ;
BEGIN
  AccessTokenType := PayPalTokenObj.Get('token_type').JsonValue ;
  Result := AccessTokenType.Value ;
  PayPalForm.Memo1.Lines.Add('Token Type: ' + Result) ;
END ; {GetTokenType}

procedure SendPayment;
const
  PaymentRequest = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment';
var
  PayPalPaymentRequestObj, PayerObj, AmountObj, TransactionObj, RedirectObj: TJSONObject;
  TransactionsArray :TJSONArray ;
  InputJSON: TStringStream;
  Result :String ;
begin
  //Create a JSON object called PayPalPaymentRequest
  PayPalPaymentRequestObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    PayPalPaymentRequestObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('intent', TJSONString.Create('sale'))) ;
    RedirectObj := TJSONObject.Create;
    try
      PayPalPaymentRequestObj.AddPair('redirect_urls', RedirectObj);
      RedirectObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('return_url', TJSONString.Create('http://www.SoftwareMomentum.com')));
      RedirectObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('cancel_url', TJSONString.Create('http://www.Yahoo.com')));
    except
      RedirectObj.Free;
      raise;
    end;

    PayerObj := TJSONObject.Create;
    try
      PayPalPaymentRequestObj.AddPair('payer', PayerObj);
      PayerObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('payment_method', TJSONString.Create('paypal')));
    except
      PayerObj.Free;
      raise;
    end;

    TransactionsArray := TJSONArray.Create;
    AmountObj := TJSONObject.Create;
    TransactionObj := TJSONObject.Create;
    try
      PayPalPaymentRequestObj.AddPair('transactions', TransactionsArray) ;
      AmountObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('total', TJSONString.Create('7.47')));
      AmountObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('currency', TJSONString.Create('USD')));
      TransactionObj.AddPair('amount', AmountObj);
      TransactionObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('description', TJSONString.Create('payment description')));
      // TransactionsArray.Add(AmountObj);
      TransactionsArray.Add(TransactionObj);
    except
      TransactionsArray.Free;
      AmountObj.Free;
      TransactionObj.Free;
      Exit;
    end;

    with Http do
    begin
      Request.Clear;
      Request.CustomHeaders.Clear ;
      Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
      Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := Format(GetTokenType + ' %s', [GetAccessToken]);
      Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
      Request.Accept := 'application/json' ;
      Request.ContentLength := 431 ;
      Request.UserAgent := 'PayPalSDK/NIW/HATEOAS' ;
    end; {with}

    InputJSON := TStringStream.Create(PayPalPaymentRequestObj.ToString, TEncoding.UTF8);

    try
      HTTP.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1 ;
      HTTP.AllowCookies := True ;
      HTTP.HandleRedirects := True ;
      //Result := HTTP.Post(PaymentRequest, PostData);
      Result := HTTP.Post(PaymentRequest, InputJSON) ;
    finally
      InputJSON.Free;
    end ; {try-finally}
  finally
    PayPalPaymentRequestObj.Free;
  end ; {try-finally}
end;
```

Comment: ...what's the point of a `try` with nothing in the `finally`?  I see lots of `Create` inside `try`.  I see `Create` with no `try`... not that this is why your code isn't working, but it makes us wonder whether this is all of your code or not?

Comment: I am new to JSON and new to Delphi so excuse me if there is some coding mistakes. I tried my best based on the Paypal Developer guide. I also mentioned this is what I have so far and not final. Other from the fact you pointed out about the try-finally, can u help me to get it to work? Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the server's actual response.  Your code is assuming that the response gets written to the same `TStream` that the request data is provided from, but that is not the case.

You are calling the version of `Post()` that takes a `TStream` as input and returns a `String` as output:

```
function Post(AURL: string; ASource: TStream): string; overload;
```

You are ignoring the returned `String` and instead using your original request data, thus the *echoing* that you are experiencing. The server is not echoing the request back to you, you are simply processing whatever you send as if it was returned.

You need to change this code:

```
HTTP.Post(PaymentRequest, Response) ;
Result := Response.DataString ;
```

To this instead:

```
Result := HTTP.Post(PaymentRequest, Response);
```

You should then rename the `Response` variable to a more suitable name.  And also clean up your memory management as well, as you have some memory leaks if something goes wrong.

Try something like this:

```
procedure SendPayment;
const
  PaymentRequest = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment';
var
  PayPalPaymentRequestObj, PayerObj, AmountObj, TransactionObj, RedirectObj: TJSONObject;
  TransactionsArray: TJSONArray;
  InputJSON: TStringStream;
  Result: String;
begin
  //Create a JSON object called PayPalPaymentRequest
  PayPalPaymentRequestObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    PayPalPaymentRequestObj.AddPair('intent', 'sale');
    RedirectObj := TJSONObject.Create;
    try
      RedirectObj.AddPair('return_url', 'http://www.SoftwareMomentum.com');
      RedirectObj.AddPair('cancel_url', 'http://www.Yahoo.com');
      PayPalPaymentRequestObj.AddPair('redirect_urls', RedirectObj);
    except
      RedirectObj.Free;
      raise;
    end;

    PayerObj := TJSONObject.Create;
    try
      PayerObj.AddPair('payment_method', 'paypal');
      PayPalPaymentRequestObj.AddPair('payer', PayerObj);
    except
      PayerObj.Free;
      raise;
    end;

    TransactionsArray := TJSONArray.Create;
    try
      TransactionObj := TJSONObject.Create;
      try
        AmountObj := TJSONObject.Create;
        try
          AmountObj.AddPair('total', '7.47');
          AmountObj.AddPair('currency', 'USD');
          TransactionObj.AddPair('amount', AmountObj);
        except
          AmountObj.Free;
          raise;
        end;
        TransactionObj.AddPair('description', 'payment description');
        TransactionsArray.Add(TransactionObj);
      except
        TransactionObj.Free;
        raise;
      end;
      PayPalPaymentRequestObj.AddPair('transactions', TransactionsArray);
    except
      TransactionsArray.Free;
      raise;
    end;

    with Http do
    begin
      ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
      AllowCookies := True;
      HandleRedirects := True;

      Request.Clear;
      Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
      Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := Format('%s %s', [GetTokenType, GetAccessToken]);
      Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
      Request.Accept := 'application/json';
      Request.UserAgent := 'PayPalSDK/NIW/HATEOAS';
    end;

    InputJSON := TStringStream.Create(PayPalPaymentRequestObj.ToString, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      Result := HTTP.Post(PaymentRequest, InputJSON);
    finally
      InputJSON.Free;
    end;
  finally
    PayPalPaymentRequestObj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Remy,Thank so much for the help and pointing some issues I was not aware of. In the try..finally block for Result := HTTP.Post(PaymentRequest, PostData); from my understanding, Result will read the results of PostData. Is this correct? Secondly, can u please tell me why Result is coming back empty after implementing the changes you suggested?  Thank you so kindly once again

Comment: The string that `Post()` returns will contain the server's response data. THAT is the data that gets assigned to `Result`, not the data from `PostData`.  The `try/finally` is merely to ensure that `PostData` gets freed from memory regardless of whether `Post()` succeeds or fails (if it fails, it raises an exception). The only way `Result` would be blank is if either 1) the server response is blank to begin with, or else 2) `Post()` is failing and raising an exception, thus bypassing the assignment of `Result` altogether.

Comment: Is there a way to test for either of these conditions? The server response is blank or Post is failing? The Post does process okay when stepping through the code.  Thanks again for the help

Comment: As I told you, `Post()` throws an exception if it fails.  That includes server error (non-2xx) responses.  You can wrap `Post()` in a `try/catch` block to handle that condition. If no exception is being thrown, then `Post()` is not failing, and so the server response must be blank. To verify that, use a debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (you cannot use a packet sniffer like Wireshark because HTTPS is being used), or attach one of Indy's own `TIdLog...` components to `TIdHTTP`. Either of those will capture the server's actual response so you can look at it.

Comment: the server is not coming back empty. I had a friend write some .net code and verified that it worked. I did figure out that my JASON was incorrect and fixed it. I believe the idHTTP.Post method is where the situation lies;

Comment: I guarantee you that this version of `Post()` works correctly. But, if you don't want to trust it, then use another version of it: `procedure Post(AURL: string; ASource, AResponseContent: TStream); overload;`  Create two `TStream` objects, one to send the request JSON, and one to receive the server's raw data. Then you can do whatever you want with that data. The only difference between this version and the other version is that this version returns the server's raw data as-is, whereas the other version decodes the server's data to a `String`.

Comment: I am using a TStringStream and creating an instance like this: PostData := TStringStream.Create(PayPalPaymentRequestObj.ToString, TEncoding.ASCII); Then I use this create in the Post like so:Result := HTTP.Post(PaymentRequest, PostData);  So how can I use a TStream and pass in the JSON since it will not allow me to do a ToString Method?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You already know how to post the JSON using a TStream. It has been shown several times in this discussion. BTW, JSON typically uses UTF8 and not ASCII, so use `TEncoding.UTF8`, like I showed you. That being said, you are missing some required HTTP headers, and your JSON data is malformed, per the [Paypal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) spec, which is probably why the server is not sending back what you are expecting. Fix your request/JSON and try again.

Comment: Hi Remy, yes you are correct regarding the Headers which I fixed as well as the JSON format which has also been corrected. But I am a bit confused when u mention TStream. Is it okat to use TStringStream for the last 2 parameters of the post? by the way, I am using Indy version 10.5.8.0. Thank u so much for your patient help. Is it possible to show you my edited code?

Comment: I am getting an Error 401. I believe this is coming from Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := Format(GetTokenType + ' %s', [GetAccessToken]); 401 says that a WWW-authenticate header must be in included in the header field. I am doing something wrong in the above line in CustomHeaders?? Thank you

Comment: You can use any `TStream`-derived class. `TStringStream` is fine for the first parameter, but I would not suggest using it for the second parameter, I would use `TMemoryStream` instead, or just omit that parameter altogether like I already showed you. Please edit the original question to show the updated code. It would also be useful to see what `GetTokenType()` and `GetAccessToken()` are actually doing. Did you verify that the String you are assigning to the Authentication header is being formatted correctly?

Comment: Hi Remy, I have updated my code as well as uploaded the GetTokenType and GetAccessToken. The JSON i believe is correctly formatted now since I have compared it with the PayPal REST API documentation. I have also used the version of HTTP.Post() which returns a string as well as used UTF8 encoding. I am getting a 401 error but not really sure where this is coming from. Thank you once again for your help. Please have a look at the updated code.

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer. The 401 error is coming from the server, and it means you are likely using an invalid/expired token_type or access_token in the `Authorization` header. Are you sure that your request to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token is actually succeeding before you send your request to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment?

Comment: Yes the token is succedding because I see a status of 200 for the token request. Token type is coming back as "Bearer". Secondly the token does not expire until 28880 seconds....8 hours so i dont think it is expired. Secondly the changes you made to CustomHeaders, the compilier stops since it is expecting an integer on GetTokenType not a string. how can I fix this if GetTokenType returns "Bearer" ??

Comment: There is no integer related to `GetTokenType()` in the code I posted.  `GetTokenType()` returns a `String`, and `%s` in `Format()` expects a String.  Where are you seeing an integer? What is the actual compiler error and line of code it is erroring on?

Comment: here is your line of code: Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := Format('%s%s' [GetTokenType, GetAccessToken]);  The compiler stops on this line and gives an error message of:E2010 Incompatible Types: Integer and String.

Comment: There is no Integer on that line. However, I just noticed a comma is missing between `'%s %s'` and `[GetTokenType, GetAccessToken]`. That must be causing a parsing error in the compiler. I have added the missing comma.

Comment: Hi Remy, i made the changes and it compiles now, however I am still getting an empty response. I new to to Delphi and new to this site, is it possible for me to email you my code and pay you to get this part working for me? Please let me know since I have tried everything including contacting Paypal

Comment: Then you have to be doing something else wrong in your handling of the API. What I showed you should be working fine. You can email me privately from my website (link is in my [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau?tab=profile)).

Comment: Hi Remy, I just emailed you my source code regarding the Token Request (which works) and the Payment Request (which does not work). I am using Delphi XE2 and Indy 10.5.8.0. Thank you once again

Comment: I have emailed you a reply.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Remy, I would like you discuss this with you, but your website's mail form is not functioning

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried in firefox/ie/chrome, filled ALL the field, tried with product specified or empty and every time I get an error that a mandatory string is empty. What I'm hoping to get license and support to add PayPal activation directly into my Delphi 7 app (Zoom Player). The end conversation on this thread seems to imply that the final working solution was not posted publicly...

Comment: @bLight I use Firefox, the webform works fine for me